# Setting working directory for custom build steps in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, working-directory, custom-build-step

Is it possible to set the working directory for a "Custom Build Step" command in a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you can set a default working directory but you can change it yourself in your custom build step.

In the ***Property Pages*** dialog for the file with the custom build step, select the ***Command Line*** field and click the `...` button:

[image: Property Pages dialog]

In the ***Command Line*** dialog, you can add multiple commands that all will be executed for the custom build. To change the working directory to **C:\MyFolder** and launch **MyProgram.exe** located in that folder, add the following lines:

[image: Command Line dialog]

An alternative is to define all this in a bat file such as **MyCustomBuild.bat** and call it in the ***Command Line*** field: `call MyCustomBuild.bat`

Comment: Spent so much time searching google, and solution is so simple :) Thanks a lot

Comment: cd now also supports changing the dive. You can now do: `cd /D c:\MyFolder` or as the working directory seems to C:\ `cd /D $(ProjectDir)`is very helpful, too.